# creating loop to add 1 and exclude elements of array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have to create a loop at the bottom of the code which prints

```
Event number 0 was recorded at 10:53
Event number 1 was recorded at 10:59
```

the loop has to create it to add 1 each time for 0 to 1 and not include all the other null elements in the array. my current code outputs

```
Record of Wombat Detection events at [100,100] 
Event number 0 was recorded at 10:53
Event number 0 was recorded at 10:59
Event number 0 was recorded at null
Event number 0 was recorded at null
Event number 0 was recorded at null
```

This is my current code

```
class RecordEvents {
   public static void main (String args[]) {
      Recorder r1 = new Recorder (100,100,"Wombat Detection");
      r1.recordEvent("10:53");
      r1.recordEvent("10:59");
      r1.printEvents();
   }
}

class Recorder {
   int xPos,yPos;
   String eventType;
   String [] event = new String [5];

   int xevent = 0;       
   Recorder (int xPos, int yPos, String eventType ) {
      this.xPos = xPos;
      this.yPos = yPos ;
      this.eventType = eventType;
   }

   void recordEvent (String eventTime ) {
      event [xevent] = eventTime;
      xevent++;
   }
   void printEvents(){
      System.out.println ("Record of " + eventType +
                       " events at [" + xPos + "," + yPos + "] " );
      for (String current: event) {
         System.out.println("Event number 0 was recorded at " + current);
      }     
   }
}
```

Comment: check if `current != null` before printing it.

Comment: Probably toy need to use `for` loop to have access to event index:
`for (int i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
class Recorder {
int xPos,yPos;
String eventType;
List<String> event = new ArrayList<String>();

int xevent = 0;
Recorder (int xPos, int yPos, String eventType ) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos ;
    this.eventType = eventType;
}

void recordEvent (String eventTime ) {
    event.add(eventTime);
    xevent++;
}
void printEvents(){
    System.out.println ("Record of " + eventType +
            " events at [" + xPos + "," + yPos + "] " );

    int index=0;
    for (String current: event) {
        String logOut=String.format("Event number %s was recorded at ",index);
        System.out.println(logOut+ current);
        index++;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your "events" array is initialised to contain 5 elements every time it is instantiated. This, your final for loop is going to run 5 times regardless of its content.

Consider using a *collection* such as a List implementation, considering the values may not be unique in this instance. This way you get dynamic sizing.

I'm not sure if this is part of your question, but you will also print out 0 for every item in that list because it's hardcoded in the System.out.println(); call you're making in your final for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make **just one change** buddy.

In the function `printEvents()`, the `for` loop iterates through the entire `event[]` array, regardless of whether all its indexes contain elements or not.

So, all you need to make is just one change. Instead of looping over the entire `event[5]` array, use a `for` which loops from `0` to `xevent`. Since it is accessible anywhere inside the `printEvents()` and it gets updated every time `recordEvent()` is called, the current value of `xevent` will be the upper bound of the filled part of the `event[]`.

**SOLUTION**:
 Replace the `for` loop in `printEvents()` with the following :

```
for (int i = 0; i < xevent; i++) {
         System.out.println("Event number " + i + " was recorded at " + event[i]);
}
```

*THE OUTPUT:*

> Record of Wombat Detection events at [100,100]
>
> Event number 0 was recorded at 10:53
>
> Event number 1 was recorded at 10:59